# how we can fix "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException:

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

i want to show the list of orders through api but we have an error in the DAO SQLSyntaxErrorException.

```
@RequestMapping("list")
    public String getAllOrders() {
        //APIResponse response=new APIResponse();
        List<OrderBeans> orderList = orderDao.selectAll();

        return new Gson().toJson(orderList);
    }
```

```
public List<OrderBeans> selectAll() {
        System.out.println("DAO => " + jdbcTemplate);
        List<OrderBeans> orders = null;
        String query = "select * from " + TABLE_ORDER +"";
        try {
            orders = jdbcTemplate.query(query, new OrderRowMapper());
        } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException | IncorrectResultSetColumnCountException e) {

        }
        return orders;
    }
```

```
3-May-2019 15:01:15.997 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-109] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/Grocery] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select * from order]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order' at line 1] with root cause
 java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order' at line 1
```

Comment: Is this code written in a special Javascript library?

Comment: do you think it will help us if you paste what is the value for TABLE_ORDER

Comment: Java & javascript are not the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am speculating here that your error is due to your SQL table being called `ORDER`, which of course is a reserved keyword in almost all versions of SQL.  You should always avoid naming your tables and columns with reserved keywords.  As a workaround, you could build your query as follows, placing backticks around the table name:

```
String query = "select * from `" + TABLE_ORDER + "`";
```

However, the above should only be viewed as a temporary solution until you get a chance to fix your data model.